# convert this LINQ code query to lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first

I want to convert this code with lambda expression

```
 var employees = from e in dataContext.AccountTrees
                        where (id.HasValue ? e.ParentId == id : e.ParentId == null)
                        select new
                        {
                            id = e.AccountId,
                            Name = e.Name,
                            hasChildren = e.AccountTrees1.Any(),
                        };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 dataContext.AccountTrees.Where(e => id.HasValue ? e.ParentId.Value == id.Value : e.ParentId == null).Select(x => new {id = e.AccountId, Name = e.Name, hasChildren = e.AccountTrees1.Any()})
```

Comment: yes i got this error https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Vq4SpLkohqSEhMcXNYV3FsQkk/view?usp=sharing